# How to synchronize the ability to deal damage from the host and client?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a health script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Unity.Netcode;

public class health : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] 
    private NetworkObject NetworkObject;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] 
    private bool isHitBox;
    [SerializeField] 
    private health basicHealth;
    [SerializeField] 
    private int healthPartsNumber;
    [SerializeField] 
    private GameObject SelfCanvas;
    [Header("Basic")]
    [SerializeField] 
    private NetworkVariable<int>[] healthParts; 
    [SerializeField] 
    private Image[] iconParts;

    private void Start() 
    {
        if (!NetworkObject.IsLocalPlayer && !isHitBox)
        {
            SelfCanvas.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private void Update() 
    {
        if (!isHitBox && NetworkObject.IsLocalPlayer)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < iconParts.Length; i++)
            {
                if (healthParts[i].Value == 100 && healthParts[i].Value > 61)
                {
                    iconParts[i].color = Color.green;
                }

                if (healthParts[i].Value <= 61 && healthParts[i].Value > 31)
                {
                    iconParts[i].color = Color.yellow;
                }

                if (healthParts[i].Value <= 31 && healthParts[i].Value > 1)
                {
                    iconParts[i].color = Color.red;
                }

                if (healthParts[i].Value <= 0)
                {
                    iconParts[i].color = Color.gray;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    public void GetDamageServerRpc(int Damage)
    {
        basicHealth.healthParts[healthPartsNumber].Value -= Damage;
    }
}
```

And function

```
[ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
public void GetDamageServerRpc(int Damage)
{
    basicHealth.healthParts[healthPartsNumber].Value -= Damage;
}
```

It works only if the client wants to damage the server. And if the server wants to give damage to the client, it doesn't work, although if you look at the health script, the values change, although the pictures do not change color. How can I fix it?

Video: https://streamable.com/1zzj49

I tried to set `serverRpc` and `clientRpc`, it didn't help.

Gun script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using Unity.Netcode;

public class weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private NetworkObject NetworkObject;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private float range = 1000f;
    [SerializeField] private Transform raycastOrigin;
    [Header("Settings")]
    [SerializeField] private int damage;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private int bulletsMax;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private bool canChangeMode;
    [SerializeField] private ShootType shootType = 0;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private float fireRate;
    [Header("particles")]
    [SerializeField] private ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
    [Header("gun recoil")]
    [SerializeField] private recoil recoil;
    [SerializeField] private float recoilX;
    [SerializeField] private float recoilY;
    [SerializeField] private float recoilZ;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private float snappiness;
    [SerializeField] private float returnSpeed;
    [Header("camera recoil")]
    [SerializeField] private recoil cameraRecoil;
    [SerializeField] private float camRecoilX;
    [SerializeField] private float camRecoilY;
    [SerializeField] private float camRecoilZ;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private float camSnappiness;
    [SerializeField] private float camReturnSpeed;
    

    private enum ShootType {auto, single}

    private int bulletNow;
    private bool canShoot;
    private float fireTime;
    private menu menu;
    private bool isOn;

    // for logs
    private TMP_Text shootTypeLog;
    private TMP_Text firedLog;
    private TMP_Text bulletsLog;

    private void Start() 
    {
        if (!NetworkObject.IsLocalPlayer)
        {
            enabled = false;
        }
        // logs
        shootTypeLog = GameObject.Find("shootTypeLog").GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
        firedLog = GameObject.Find("firedLog").GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
        bulletsLog = GameObject.Find("bulletsLog").GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
        
        bulletNow = bulletsMax;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (recoil != null)
        {
            recoil.RecoilParams(recoilX, recoilY, recoilZ, snappiness, returnSpeed);
        }
        else
        {
            recoil = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("local recoil").GetComponent<recoil>();
        }

        if (cameraRecoil != null)
        {
            cameraRecoil.RecoilParams(camRecoilX, camRecoilY, camRecoilZ, camSnappiness, camReturnSpeed);
        }
        else
        {
            cameraRecoil = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("local recoil cam").GetComponent<recoil>();
        }

        if (menu != null)
        {
            isOn = menu.GetMenuStatus();
        }
        else
        {
            menu = GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<menu>();
        }
        
        fireTimer();

        if (!isOn)
        {
            // change fire type
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V) && canChangeMode)
            {
                if (shootType == ShootType.auto)
                {
                    shootType = ShootType.single;
                }
                else
                {
                    shootType = ShootType.auto;
                }
            }

            // reload
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R) && bulletNow != bulletsMax)
            {
                bulletNow = bulletsMax;
            }

            // shoot
            if (shootType == ShootType.auto)
            {
                if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && bulletNow != 0 && canShoot)
                {
                    Fire();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && bulletNow != 0 && canShoot)
                {
                    Fire();
                }
            }
        }
 
        //logs
        shootTypeLog.text = $"shootType: {shootType}";
        firedLog.text = $"fired: {canShoot}";
        bulletsLog.text = $"bullets: {bulletNow}";
    }

    private void Fire()
    {
        bulletNow--;
        canShoot = false;
        recoil.RecoilFire();
        cameraRecoil.RecoilFire();

        ParticleSystem mz = Instantiate(muzzleFlash, raycastOrigin);
        // mz.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn(true);
        mz.GetComponent<connectToOrigin>().ConnectOrigin(raycastOrigin);

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(raycastOrigin.position, raycastOrigin.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            health health = hit.collider.GetComponent<health>();
            if (health != null)
            {
                health.GetDamageServerRpc(damage);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void fireTimer()
    {
        if (!canShoot)
        {
            if (fireTime >= 0)
            {
                fireTime -= Time.deltaTime;
                canShoot = false;
            }
            else
            {
                canShoot = true;
                fireTime = fireRate;    
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawRay(raycastOrigin.position, raycastOrigin.forward * range);
    }
}
```

A function that deals damage:

```
private void Fire()
{
    bulletNow--;
    canShoot = false;
    recoil.RecoilFire();
    cameraRecoil.RecoilFire();

    ParticleSystem mz = Instantiate(muzzleFlash, raycastOrigin);
    // mz.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn(true);
    mz.GetComponent<connectToOrigin>().ConnectOrigin(raycastOrigin);

    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(raycastOrigin.position, raycastOrigin.forward, out hit, range))
    {
        health health = hit.collider.GetComponent<health>();

        if (health != null)
        {
            health.GetDamageServerRpc(damage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to look at rpc calls, and decide whos the authorative and call accordingly

Comment: `GetDamageServerRpc` is executed on the server and thereby allows a client to deal damage to the server ... I don't see anything for synchronizing back the damage from server to clients .. how exactly is this supposed to be done?

Comment: and also why does your `health` component have a second reference to another `health basicHealth` component ..? Also `NetworkObject` sounds redundant as this already is a `NetworkBehaviour` ..

Comment: @derHugo 
basicHealth leaves a link to the main script, because I have it on different parts of my body to make hitboxes and to make sure that each hitbox has its own health.
How do I make it so that not only the server synchronizes with the client, but also the client, so that they can deal damage to each other, this is what interests me (I don't know how it should be)